# Is Rails ORM working this way?

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

Recently, i needed to implement ORM like Active Record but using php. So the first thing i want to write is the record creation. As long as every record treated like an object, you can assign values directly into the class attributes like so:

```
p = Product.new
p.name = "Some Book"
```

And than creation method called.

So, what i want to know, if ActiveRecord first sends query to the database with `"DESCRIBE table_name"` to look what columns it has and then turn them into class attributes?

If it's like so, is this method good for performance (you need to send query every time you make an object of the model)?

Comment: I believe there are many AR pattern implementation in php. As for your question, you can start from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_cache`

Answer (score 1):

No, ActiveRecord doesn't query db when you create new instance of a Model class. In ruby, `attr_accessor` helps in defining `getter`s and `setter`s, and in rails you can verify in console as

```
p = Product.new
#=> #<Product id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

No db call, just a new Product class object.

Comment: I'm confused that it lets user to pass the value to an unexisting attribute of the class (model). So, it's probably have some setter defined and when user is trying to set some attribute, it get's saved into some sort of array which will be triggered when CREATE method called and then check if the attribute name is matching the name in the table, right?